# How to use gltf animation extension in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gltf, windows-mixed-reality

Hoping someone can explain or point me in the right direction for help in getting glTF animations to play in Mixed Reality viewer and in PowerPoint.
I’m using Visual Studio Code with the glTF Tools Extension (21.16) to try and add an Animation trigger to my glb file (which was exported from Blender).

However, I keep getting a glTF Validation error: Unsupported extension encountered: ‘EXT_animation_map’.
I’m following the instructions from this Microsoft Mixed Reality guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/creating-3d-models-for-use-in-the-windows-mixed-reality-home#animation-guidelines

I also tried it using code from the FB_animation_map extension below but also got Extension not found error:
https://github.com/msfeldstein/glTF/blob/04f7005206257cf97b215df5e3f469d7838c1fee/extensions/Vendor/FB_animation_map/README.md

Is there something else I need installed or configured in Visual Studio to make this work?

Comment: You may want to file a bug on the VSCode extension: https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/gltf-vscode. I suspect it simply doesn't support that extension, which is not a standardized part of the glTF format.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this already got answered on the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/gltf-vscode/issues/122).  But, just to close this out, this message here:

> glTF Validation error: Unsupported extension encountered: ‘EXT_animation_map’

This is a harmless message, it just means that the glTF Validator itself doesn't contain code to validate the contents of the named extension.  It doesn't indicate any problem with the extension being there.

On the GitHub issue, the author of the glTF Validator mentions that the wording of this message will be improved in the next release.